# howto handle form referencing queries in access with a sql-server backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, forms

I upsized an ms-access 2003 database to sql-server 2008 but can't get my head around how to handle queries who need a parameter.

E.g. there is a query and in its where clause a form field is referenced via Forms!my_form!aField. 
How can I pass the value of "aField" to ms-sqlserver.
By now my only idea is to modify the record source using VBA and append the value there.

Also if the query does not reference a form but is bound to a very large table or a query that returns a lot of data, it is recommended to reduce the number of records returned by the server - how can I ensure this.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Ramon

Comment: It should just work, because (presumably) you're using linked tables, so the Access expression service will still be able to resolve the control reference before handing off the SQL to the server for retrieval. I'd strongly suggest declaring a parameter for the control in order to allow the Jet/ACE query optimizer to do the best job possible. In general, I never store control references in the recordsources of forms/reports nor in saved QueryDefs, so this is not an issue I've encountered in my upsized apps.

Comment: Of cause, linked tables do work. But often all data is passed back from the server to the form and gets filtered by access, which is something you don't really want. Do you have, by any chance, a link handy where the declaration of parameters for controls is described?

Comment: It's standard SQL, but you can figure it out by declaring the parameter using the QBE interface and then see what SQL gets written.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, when you upsize the database, any forms and queries using migrated tables should be automatically updated.  You'd simply make sure they are referenced properly on the front end, and the SQL-Server manages the data on the backend transparently.

Binding a form to a table is usually never a good idea - since a query can be written to give you the narrow-est displaying of data useful without pulling every single record in the table.  Granted, you can use filters, but then you've already polled the database for all the records, your just altering your view.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry, I used table, view and query interchangeably. Still a query can return a lot of data and I don't get how to pass a parameter to a query which resides server side without changing the recordsouce via vba.

Comment: So, you want to dynamically rewrite your queries without changing your recordsource attributes on your forms?  I am confused.

Comment: I want to add a where clause without using vba to change the recordsouce. I found out when using ADP there is a possibility to define input parameters using the properties dialog of a form. I am looking for a way to do the same using a MBD.